# Save a data.frame of a list as a csv file in R

Tags: r, list, function, csv, dataframe

I have an object named `output` that is of class `data.frame`containing a list. I was wondering if it might be possible to save `output` as a `csv` file from R?

**Here is my code:**

```
d <- data.frame(list(A = c(kap = 2, sap = 3), B = c(kap = 1, sap = 4)))

d[] <- lapply(d, as.list)  ## This step is required to show `TRUE` and `FALSE` in `output`

output <- data.frame(t(d), dap = c(T, F))

write.csv(output, "output.csv") # Error: unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Comment: The  `output` is a `list` of columns.  Do you want it that way?

Comment: You can try: `data.table::fwrite(output, file = "output.csv")` instead of `write.csv`

Comment: You may need `output <- data.frame(lapply(output, unlist))`

Comment: Also, can't you just do `d <- data.frame(list(A = c(kap = 2, sap = 3), B = c(kap = 1, sap = 4)));data.frame(t(d), dap = c(TRUE, FALSE))` after the first initialisation of 'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can create the  `data.frame` after transposing the  'd', then it should also  work

```
output <-  data.frame(t(d), dap = c(TRUE, FALSE))
row.names(output) <- NULL
```

---

The `lapply` in the second line of code is looping over column and then applying the `as.list` i.e. it creating a `list` of `lists`

```
lapply(d, as.list)
#$A
#$A[[1]]
#[1] 2

#$A[[2]]
#[1] 3


#$B
#$B[[1]]
#[1] 1

#$B[[2]]
#[1] 4
```

When we assign it to 'd' with keeping the same structure (`[]`), it would remain as a `data.frame` with `list` columns

```
d[] <- lapply(d, as.list) 
str(d)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ A:List of 2  # each column is a `list`
#  ..$ : num 2
#  ..$ : num 3
# $ B:List of 2
#  ..$ : num 1
#  ..$ : num 4
```

Now, we are doing the `rbind`

```
rbind(d, dap = c(T, F))
#      A     B
#kap    2     1
#sap    3     4
#dap TRUE FALSE
```

and its transpose,

```
output <-  t(rbind(d, dap = c(T, F)))
output
#  kap sap dap  
#A 2   3   TRUE 
#B 1   4   FALSE
```

which may look like a regular data.frame output, but it is not

```
str(output)
#List of 6
# $ : num 2
# $ : num 1
# $ : num 3
# $ : num 4
# $ : logi TRUE
# $ : logi FALSE
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 3
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "kap" "sap" "dap"
```

which is again wrappedd with `data.frame`

```
str(data.frame(output))
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ kap:List of 2
#  ..$ A: num 2
#  ..$ B: num 1
# $ sap:List of 2
#  ..$ A: num 3
#  ..$ B: num 4
# $ dap:List of 2
#  ..$ A: logi TRUE
#  ..$ B: logi FALSE
```

still a `data.frame` with `list` columns.  One option is to loop over the `list`, `unlist` the `list` columns and wrap with `data.frame`

#### data

```
d <- data.frame(list(A = c(kap = 2, sap = 3), B = c(kap = 1, sap = 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some of the columns of the data-frame are not columns but rather they are of type list, you can solve this by unnesting the data;

Here are two ways that you can do;

```
# Creating data
d <- data.frame(list(A = c(kap = 2, sap = 3), B = c(kap = 1, sap = 4)))
d[] <- lapply(d, as.list)  ## This step is required to show `TRUE` and `FALSE` in `output`

# Method one using dplyr (Recommended)
output <- dplyr::tibble(t(rbind(d, dap = c(T, F))))

# Method two unnesting data using tidyr
output <- tidyr::unnest(data.frame(t(rbind(d, dap = c(T, F)))))

# Output the data
write.csv(output, "output.csv")
```